# "Access is denied" for a wcf deployed as SharePoint 2010 solution

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, exception, permissions

I've created a wcf (C# Visual Studio 2010) and installed the wsp on a SharePoint 2010 Server (not on the same machine) as solution. In der Studio-Project, the svc and config files are located in a subfolder of the mapped ISAPI-Folder. The deployment in SharePoint works good and the svc-file in the virtual _vti_bin folder on IIS7.5 is browsable. In a testclient I can set the reference to the service. No problem when I call a method which gives me back a "Hello World". But when I try to read values from Sharepoint, then I allways get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException was unhandled
  Message=Access is denied.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms.SharePointService_Share.ISharePointService.GetDocumentTitles()
       at mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms.SharePointService_Share.SharePointServiceClient.GetDocumentTitles() in D:\MGBScratch\src\sharepoint\mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms\Service References\SharePointService_Share\Reference.cs:line 57
       at mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms.TestFormWCF..ctor() in D:\MGBScratch\src\sharepoint\mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms\TestFormWCF.cs:line 23
       at mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms.Program.Main() in D:\MGBScratch\src\sharepoint\mgbahn.sharepoint.test.forms\Program.cs:line 15
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

It makes no difference, what kind of information I try to read from the Sharepoint, the error is always the same.

I'm really new in wcf and my knowledges in IIS are very small.

Comment: Was the test client a console application by any chance?

Comment: The testclient is a winform application

Comment: Have you set up a proxy class?

Comment: In the testclient I have set a service reference to the *.svc file of the server. Then in the code I create the wcf service object like

SharePointService_Share.SharePointServiceClient svc = new SharePointService_Share.SharePointServiceClient();

from there I can call the  service methods

Comment: by adding a service reference.XML get created in the app config, Can you see <System.ServiceModel> in your app config with loads of other settings?

Comment: yes... <System.ServiceModel><bindings><basicHttpBinding><binding... and <client><endpoint...

Comment: as I have decribed...I can call a wcf-method which gives back a "Hello World" but not, if I try to read values from sharepoint

Comment: I believe the above <system.ServiceModel> has to be placed in the web config somewhere but i cannot be sure as i couldn't get mine to work. This might be a step in the right direction but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Check also that wcf ports are not blocked by firewall.